# Help me solve this question if not atleast tell me What are the backgrounds needed to study to solve this question about Kenmotsu Manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, multilinear-algebra

So how do I solve this
 (, )= (, ) + 1

+3

× [ (, )  −  (, )

−  (, )  +  (, )

- (, )  −  (, ) 
  −  (, )  +  (, )
- 2 (, )  + 2 (, )
- ()  ()  −  ()  (, ) 
  + ()  (, ) − ()  () ]
  − +−1
  +3 [ (, )  −  (, )
- 2 (, ) ]
- 

+3 [ ()  (, ) − ()  ()

- ()  () − ()  (, ) ]
  − −4
  +3 [ (, ) − (, ) ] This entire thing is just one equation I don't know why it's been reflecting in bullet points. I need to get this above equation into this form and I need to understand how it works.
   (, )  = [1 −

+3

+
4
+3] [ () − () ]

.,I'm doing a project on this and I do have the idea of what smooth manifold is topologically, but that's not helping me to understand this. What and all concepts I should go through to understand this and able to solve these sort of questions. Btw this is Kenmotsu Manifold in Ricci Solitons. My current problem is how equation 24 was manipulated into 25[Kenmotsu Manifold in Ricci Solitons img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwoHe.jpg): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5HZc.jpg[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5HZc.jpg%5B1%5D)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwoHe.jpg)Here is the image
Edit:
The thing is I'm assigned to a guide who told me that I don't need any background to solve this. But does that work I'm not even getting the meaning of a single term. So please help me, I need something that will help me understand those. I'm ready to do hardwork but I don't want to put my work into something that won't help me in the project. My project consists of solving these types of questions and finally solving the unsolved questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please guide me I'm new here, there's the image link please open it.

Comment: The thing is I'm assigned to a guide who told me that I don't need any background to solve this. But does that work I'm not even getting the meaning of a single term. So please help me, I need something that will help me understand those. I'm ready to do hardwork but I don't want to put my work into something that won't help me in the project. As I want to spend my ample time into the right thing. My project consists of solving these types of questions and finally solving the unsolved questions.